# Partial loss of elements' text content using lxml

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, lxml

I have some HTML markup, where I want to get rid of some `<b>` children of a `<center>` element (it's legacy markup...).

**Problem:**  Some of the containing `<center>` elements' text vanishes when I remove the children using **Python** and **lxml**.

**Example program** (with simplified illustrative markup):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from lxml import html, etree
from lxml.etree import tostring

html_snippet = """
<center>
    <b>IT wisdoms</b>
    <b>
        for your <a href="#">brain</a>:
    </b>
    NEVER <a href="#">change a running system</a> before the holidays!
</center>"""

tree = html.fromstring(html_snippet)
center_elem = tree.xpath("//center")[0]

print('----- BEFORE -----')
print(tostring(center_elem, pretty_print=True, encoding='unicode'))
for elem in center_elem.xpath("b"):
    elem.getparent().remove(elem)
print('----- AFTER -----')
print(tostring(center_elem, pretty_print=True, encoding='unicode'))
```

**Output:**

```
----- BEFORE -----
<center>
    <b>IT wisdoms</b>
    <b>
        for your <a href="#">brain</a>:
    </b>
    NEVER <a href="#">change a running system</a> before the holidays!
</center>

----- AFTER -----
<center>
    <a href="#">change a running system</a> before the holidays!
</center>
```

As you can see, the `<b>` children are gone, but the word **NEVER** disappears, whereas the `<a>` element and the text **before the holidays!** stay.

I can't figure out how to keep it!

Comment: Do you want to remove the bold elements or just remove the bold tags?

Comment: @James: the elements and everything they contain, that is the whole nodes - this _does_ work as I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `drop_tree()` on the elements you want to eliminate:

```
tree = html.fromstring(html_snippet)
center_elem = tree.xpath("//center")[0]
print('----- BEFORE -----')
print(etree.tostring(center_elem, pretty_print=True, encoding='unicode'))
for elem in center_elem.xpath("b"):
    elem.drop_tree()
print('----- AFTER -----')
print(etree.tostring(center_elem, pretty_print=True, encoding='unicode'))
```

Returns:

```
----- BEFORE -----
<center>
    <b>IT wisdoms</b>
    <b>
        for your <a href="#">brain</a>:
    </b>
    NEVER <a href="#">change a running system</a> before the holidays!
</center>

----- AFTER -----
<center>


    NEVER <a href="#">change a running system</a> before the holidays!
</center>
```

Comment: Excellent! Apparently, "NEVER" is the tail text of the preceding node `<b>` and therefore associated with it. It's a bit unintuitive, as it is technically not within this element.

Comment: No problem.  Please remember to mark as answered :)